# Cakephp work queue

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, cakephp-2.0, amazon-sqs

i'm looking for use a work queue to delegate some jobs. 
I know that some service like Amazon SQS or Beanstalkd are perfect for this problem. 
But, in both I have to create a daemon that poll the queue every x seconds. 
Is there other ways to do that with some kind of push system?

Someone has experience with SQS+SNS to call the workers?

Thanks.

Comment: I use RabbitMQ and Celery workers, works pretty nice.